# How can I parse a .frd file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, frequency

A .frd file is a type of multi-column numeric data table used for storing information about the frequency response of speakers. A .frd file looks something like this when opened in a text editor:

```
2210.4492       89.1    -157.7
2216.3086       88.99   -157.7
2222.168        88.88   -157.6
2228.0273       88.77   -157.4
```

Using javascript, is there a way that I can parse this data in order to return each column separately?

For example, from the .frd file above, I would need to return the values like so:

```
var column1 = [2210.4492, 2216.3086, 2222.168, 2228.0273];

var column2 = [89.1, 88.99, 88.88, 88.77];

var column3 = [-157.7, -157.7, -157.6, -157.4];
```

I'm not exactly sure where to begin in trying to achieve this, so any step in the right direction would be helpful!

Comment: You should look into the technology of `regular expression(regex)`, here's a `regex` that might or might not fit your needs `([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)\n`, but I think after you study for regex you will find the best syntax for your needs, cheers!

Comment: You can use website like http://jsregex.com/ and paste `([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)\n` to regex, paste your text into `Text`, then, paste `$1 | $2 | $3` to replacement. Finally, click `replace` and `global` radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following [description](http://www.cross-spectrum.com/weblog/2010/03/05) of the FRD file format and I will follow it.

Let's assume that the content of your `.frd` file is in the variable called `content` (the following example is for Node.js):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const content = fs.readFileSync('./input.frd').toString();
```

Now if `content` has your FRD data, it means it's a set of lines, each line contains exactly three numbers: a frequency (Hz), a level (dB), and a phase (degrees). To split your `content` into lines, we can just literally `split` it:

```js
const lines = content.split(/\r?\n/);
```

(normally, splitting just by `'\n'` would've worked, but let's explicitly support Windows-style line breaks `\r\n` just in case. The `/\r?\n/` is a regular expression that says "maybe `\r`, then `\n`")

To parse each line into three numbers, we can do this:

```js
const values = line.split(/\s+/);
```

If the file can contain empty lines, it may make sense to double check that the line has exactly three values:

```js
if (values.length !== 3) {
  // skip this line
}
```

Given that we have three values in `values`, as strings, we can assign the corresponding variables:

```js
const [frequency, level, phase] = values.map(value => Number(value));
```

(`.map` converts all the values in `values` from strings to `Number` - let's do this to make sure we store the correct type).

Now putting all those pieces together:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const content = fs.readFileSync('./input.frd').toString();

const frequencies = [];
const levels = [];
const phases = [];

const lines = content.split(/\r?\n/);
for (const line of lines) {
  const values = line.split(/\s+/);
  if (values.length !== 3) {
    continue;
  }
  const [frequency, level, phase] = values.map(value => Number(value));
  frequencies.push(frequency);
  levels.push(level);
  phases.push(phase);
}

console.log(frequencies);
console.log(levels);
console.log(phases);
```

The main code (the one that works with `content`) will also work in browser, not just in Node.js, if you need that.

This code can be written in a tons of different ways, but I tried to make it easier to explain so did something very straightforward.

To use it in Node.js (if your JavaScript file is called `index.js`):

```
$ cat input.frd 
2210.4492       89.1    -157.7
2216.3086       88.99   -157.7
2222.168        88.88   -157.6
2228.0273       88.77   -157.4

$ node index.js 
[ 2210.4492, 2216.3086, 2222.168, 2228.0273 ]
[ 89.1, 88.99, 88.88, 88.77 ]
[ -157.7, -157.7, -157.6, -157.4 ]
```

Comment: My hat goes off to you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!